# Call multiple methods in same Service from Spring WebService

Tags: spring, design-patterns

I am working on a Spring 2.0 WebService, which needs to invoke one among the multiple methods of a legacy service, based on one of the attributes of the WebService Request. I do not want to write an if/else check in my @endpoint to achieve this. What kind of design pattern should I use to make this more cleaner and maintainable in future so that when new order types (refer sample code below) have to be supported, I need not add another else block.

```
@Endpoint
public class OrderServiceEndPoint {
    @Autowired
    private OrderLegacyService orderService;

    @PayloadRoot
    public @ResponsePayload OrderResponse processRequest(
                         @RequestPayload OrderRequest request) {
        if ("Create".equals(request.type)) {
             return orderService.createOrder(request);
        } else if ("Modify".equals(request.type)) {
             return orderService.modifyOrder(request);
        } else if ("Return".equals(request.type)) {
             return orderService.returnOrder(request);
        } else if ("Replace".equals(request.type)) {
             return orderService.replaceOrder(request);
        } else {
             throw new RequestNotSupportedException();
        }

    }
```

I have used org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean to implement Factory pattern in cases where I have more than one implementation of the same service, like a CreateOrderService, ModifyOrderService, ReplaceOrderService etc. But in this case, I have to invoke multiple methods of the same service. I cannot change the legacy service interface at this time as it's consumed already by another web application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7 (Which may not be the case), Java 7 supports switching on Strings. So you can write:

```
switch(request.type) {
  case "Create": return orderService.createOrder(request);
  case "Modify": return orderService.modifyOrder(request);
  case "Return": return orderService.returnOrder(request);
  case "Replace": return orderService.replaceOrder(request);
  default: throw new RequestNotSupportedException();
}
```

If you're using Java 6 or previous versions, create an enum type:

```
public enum RequestType {
  CREATE,MODIFY,RETURN,REPLACE;
}
```

The you can use the following in your code:

```
switch (RequestType.valueOf(requestType.toUpperCase())) {
  case CREATE: return orderService.createOrder(request);
  case MODIFY: return orderService.modifyOrder(request);
  case RETURN: return orderService.returnOrder(request);
  case REPLACE: return orderService.replaceOrder(request);
  default: throw new RequestNotSupportedException();
}
```

Comment: And I would probably put that code inside an adapter class (eg: OrderLegacyServiceAdapter) such that if I need to call it again on another method I don't have to repeat myself